# ASP.NET MVC how to show DropDownList

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to add Items into DropDownList without database.
 But output only shows  "Testing..."

**My Model class.**

```
public class DropDownListData
{
    public DropDownListData()
    {
        City = new List<SelectListItem> { };
    }
    public List<SelectListItem> City;
}
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Travel()
{
    DropDownListData ddld = new DropDownListData();

    ddld.City = new List<SelectListItem>
    {
        new SelectListItem {Value = "Paris" ,Text = "Paris"},
        new SelectListItem {Value = "Moscow",Text = "Moscow"},
        new SelectListItem {Value = "Yerevan" ,Text = "Yerevan" }
    };
    return View(ddld);
}
```

**View**

```
@model ASP.NET.Test.Models.DropDownListData

@{
    Layout = null;
}

Testing...
@{
    Html.DropDownList("series", Model.City, "Choose City");
}
```

Why I don't see DropDownList. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following code to directly output your DropDownList as expected:

```
@Html.DropDownList("series", Model.City, "Choose City");
```

Your current usage is generally going to function as a "code block" as demonstrated by the example below:

```
@{
    // This code will be executed and can be used to set variables, etc.
    var answer = 42;
}

<!-- This is an example of outputting your value -->
<p>
    The answer to the question is <b>@answer</b>.
</p>
```

So your current code would simply call the `Html.DropDownList()` method, but would never actually use or output it. However, prepending it with the `@` character will treat it as an expression and output it accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use:

```
@Html.DropDownList("series", Model.City, "Choose City")
```

instead of:

```
@{
    Html.DropDownList("series", Model.City, "Choose City");
}
```

What you did just calls the DropDownList function, doing nothing with the `MvcHtmlString` returned. ReSharper actually gives me a warning that the return value is not used.